# Question I answered "disappeared"

Tags: support, migration, deleted-questions

I answered a question within the last week. It got a couple of upvotes, however, I can no longer find the question that was asked. I did a search through my reputation and I don't see the question there. I also did a search through my recent activity and I don't see the question there either. Is there a way to see if the question was migrated to another site or if it was deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you answered was migrated to [IT Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4844/how-can-you-become-a-competent-web-application-security-expert-without-breaking-t). There, you'll find your answer: if you log in on IT Security.SE, you should automatically reclaim ownership of it.

When a question gets migrated, all answers are deleted and reposted on the destination site. As a normal user, deleted questions and answers don't appear in searches or on your profile.